# Primitive of $x^{-\alpha} (1-x)^{-\beta}$, $\alpha,\beta \ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, indefinite-integrals

Let be $\alpha,\beta \ge 1$. Is there a simple, "explicit" formula for the primitive of $f(x) = x^{-\alpha} (1-x)^{-\beta}$, $x\in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is not an integer, it is
 $$\frac{x^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha} \; {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(\beta,1-\alpha;\,2-\alpha;\,x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Chebyshev criterion](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chebyshev_theorem_on_the_integration_of_binomial_differentials) for binomial integrals.